# OpenSSL BIO thread safety

Tags: c++, openssl

OpenSSL's FAQ about thread safety says the following:

> Yes but with some limitations; for example, an SSL connection cannot be used concurrently by multiple threads. This is true for most OpenSSL objects.

It does not allow me to understand whether the following will be safe:

1. I call a blocking read on a BIO
2. If my application should be terminated before the response is received, I call close on that BIO

Comment: Only way to be certain is to read the source, but I would expect `BIO_close` to call the underlying `close` method, which will abort a `read` in the other thread.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by you "call close on that BIO"? There is no such function as `BIO_close` - so what specifically are you calling to close the BIO?

Comment: @MattCaswell now I get BIO's fd and the call close(fd)

Comment: If you're trying to use SSL in multiple threads you have a much bigger problem than whether OpenSSL itself is thread-safe. Even multi-threading on plaintext sockets is highly problematic. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @user207421 just in order to interrupt blocking operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSL does not guarantee thread safety if you call 2 functions using the same BIO object at the same time from 2 different threads. However that is not what you are doing.

You are sharing an *fd* between two different threads. One copy of the fd is being used by the OpenSSL library in the `BIO_read()` call in one thread, and you are calling `close()` on the same fd in a different thread.

Sharing an fd in this way is allowed on Linux so there should be no problems in your case. I can't speak for Windows.

Comment: But such an approach, as I understand, will work only for linux, nit for Windows? Since the process of socket closure is different for these OS?

Comment: I clarified my answer. I was specifically talking about Linux. I don't know for Windows.